# Scrapy gets stuck with IIS 5.1 page

Tags: python, asp.net, iis, scrapy, iis-5

I'm writing spiders with scrapy to get some data from a couple of applications using ASP. Both webpages are almost identical and requires to log in before starting scrapping, but I only managed to scrap one of them. In the other one scrapy gets waiting something forever and never gets after the login using `FormRequest` method.

The code of both spiders (they are almost identical but with different IPs) is as following:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
name = "my_very_nice_spider"
allowed_domains = ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
start_urls = ['http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/reporting/']

def parse(self,response):
    #Simulate user login on (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/reporting/)
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                      formdata={'user':'the_username',
                                                'password':'my_nice_password'},
                                      callback=self.after_login)]

def after_login(self,response):
    inspect_response(response,self) #Spider never gets here in one site
    if "Bad login" in response.body:
        print "Login failed"
        return
    #Scrapping code begins...
```

Wondering what could be different between them I used Firefox Live HTTP Headers for inspecting the headers and found only one difference: the webpage that works uses IIS 6.0 and the one that doesn't IIS 5.1.

As this alone couldn't explain myself why one works and the other doesnt' I used Wireshark to capture network traffic and found this:

Interaction using scrapy with working webpage (IIS 6.0)

```
scrapy  --> webpage GET /reporting/ HTTP/1.1
scrapy  <-- webpage HTTP/1.1 200 OK
scrapy  --> webpage POST /reporting/ HTTP/1.1 (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
scrapy  <-- webpage HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved
scrapy  --> webpage GET /reporting/htm/webpage.asp
scrapy  <-- webpage HTTP/1.1 200 OK
scrapy  --> webpage POST /reporting/asp/report1.asp
...Scrapping begins
```

Interaction using scrapy with not working webpage (IIS 5.1)

```
scrapy  --> webpage GET /reporting/ HTTP/1.1
scrapy  <-- webpage HTTP/1.1 200 OK
scrapy  --> webpage POST /reporting/ HTTP/1.1 (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
scrapy  <-- webpage HTTP/1.1 100 Continue # What the f...?
scrapy  <-- webpage HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved
...Scrapy waits forever...
```

I googled a little bit and found that indeed IIS 5.1 has some nice kind of "feature" that makes it return HTTP 100 whenever someone makes a POST to it [as shown here](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=2184).

Knowing that the root of all evil is where always is, but having to scrap that site anyway... How can I make scrapy work in this situation? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Edit - Console log with not working site:

```
2014-01-17 09:09:50-0300 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.20.2 started (bot: mybot)
2014-01-17 09:09:50-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2014-01-17 09:09:50-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': bot.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': [bot.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'bot'}
2014-01-17 09:09:51-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-01-17 09:09:51-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-01-17 09:09:51-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-01-17 09:09:51-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines:
2014-01-17 09:09:51-0300 [my_very_nice_spider] INFO: Spider opened
2014-01-17 09:09:51-0300 [my_very_nice_spider] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-01-17 09:09:51-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-01-17 09:09:51-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-01-17 09:09:54-0300 [my_very_nice_spider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/reporting/> (referer: None)
2014-01-17 09:10:51-0300 [my_very_nice_spider] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-01-17 09:11:51-0300 [my_very_nice_spider] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-01-17 09:12:51-0300 [my_very_nice_spider] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-01-17 09:12:54-0300 [my_very_nice_spider] DEBUG: Retrying <POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/reporting/> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/reporting/ took longer than 180 seconds..
2014-01-17 09:13:51-0300 [my_very_nice_spider] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-01-17 09:14:51-0300 [my_very_nice_spider] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-01-17 09:15:51-0300 [my_very_nice_spider] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-01-17 09:15:54-0300 [my_very_nice_spider] DEBUG: Retrying <POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/reporting/> (failed 2 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/reporting/ took longer than 180 seconds..
...
```

Comment: can you share your console log?

Comment: Just added console log... Do you need anything else?

Comment: Now you have timeouts? also is the POST URL the same as for the working case? the logs shows `POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/reporting/` compared to `POST /reporting/index.asp` before (that may be due to your rewriting of the logs before posting here).
Since you use Wireshark, can you see anything different in the headers? Did you compare the queries with what a browser does?

Comment: Well, maybe I didn't explain myself very well... The main problem is scrapy keeps having timeouts all the time (seems as it keeps waiting for something forever). And yes, you're right, sorry for the confusion, the POST address should be the same all the time, I forgot to clean them (just edited).

Comment: I just checked interaction using browser with Wireshark and didn't found any significant difference: Even using the same USER_AGENT as the browser doesn't help. The interaction between browser and the site is basically the same as the working site but with the `HTTP 100` response in the middle:  `GET /reporting/ -> HTTP 200` then `POST /reporting/ -> 100 Continue -> 302 Moved` then `GET /reporting/htm/webpage.asp` etc..

Comment: If Scrapy keep `Retrying`, that would mean the server is not sending back anything in reply to the `POST` request (you should be able to check that with Wireshark). And as @Rho mentions, this might be due to HTTP/1.1. HTTP/1.0 will open a TCP connection for every request/response dialog. HTTP/1.1 keeps the TCP connection alive until one of the parties tears it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the HTTP 1.0 downloader:

```
# settings.py
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    'http': 'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http10.HTTP10DownloadHandler',
    'https': 'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http10.HTTP10DownloadHandler',
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works flawlessly! I will keep it in mind when scrapping IIS 5.1 servers

Comment: @kmixflow I'd suggest to add this issue to https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues because the default handler it should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rho , I will submit this issue there then... I was suspecting that there was no good reason behind being able to scrap only one of the applications.